# Jquery dialog big white x for close style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I make the close button for a jquery dialog modal bigger and white like this [White Close image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcK7Q.png) I've tried taking out the image url and using other styles but to no avail going to try to modify image to see where that gets me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: inside Jquery-ui-xxx/images there is a set of icons, "inspect" your close icon and see which one you are using. You can try to modify those or play with a Jquery UI theme that work for you.